# Visual Studio errors in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm new to C++ and have just learned about pointers. I was just trying to print the new variable(10) to the console as per the below code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define LOG(x) std::cout << x << std:endl;

int main() 
{   
    int var = 8;
    int* ptr = &var;
    *ptr = 10;
    LOG(var);
    std::cin.get();
}
```

When I tried to run the code I got these errors successively in Visual-Studio:

> "Error (active)   E0728   a namespace name is not allowed"
>   "Error    C2882   'std': illegal use of namespace identifier in expression"
>   "Error    C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before ':'"
>   "Error    C2059   syntax error: ':'"

Below you can see the build output errors:

> "1>------ Build started: Project: HelloWorld, Configuration: Debug
>   Win32 ------   1>Main.cpp   1>c:\dev\cherno
>   c++\helloworld\helloworld\main.cpp(11): error C2882: 'std': illegal
>   use of namespace identifier in expression   1>c:\dev\cherno
>   c++\helloworld\helloworld\main.cpp(11): error C2143: syntax error:
>   missing ';' before ':'   1>c:\dev\cherno
>   c++\helloworld\helloworld\main.cpp(11): error C2059: syntax error: ':'
>   1>Done building project "HelloWorld.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped =========="

Please help if you can.

Comment: In the macro for LOG, you have a missing ':' for std::endl

Comment: _I'm new to C++_ first rule: don’t use macros! Write a function.

Comment: Also, in C++ you don't need to use pointers as much as in C. Try to avoid them. And your line `LOG(var);` expands to a line ending in `;;`, is that what you intended? Also, you have an `int` function that doesn't return anything; I'd stay away from that practice. And I must protest strongly to using the program name "HelloWorld" for a program that outputs 10.

Comment: @MrLister I think he's learning the pointer assignment and dereferencing, which is why he changes the value using the pointer... Nonetheless you're right

Comment: Hey guys - many thanks for your feedback, very helpful. That's quite embarrassing, I can't believe I missed the ":".